# como sacar promedios de esta matriz

Tags: python, matriz

```
precios= [['iPad','iPhone','SamsungGalaxy'],[285,559,82],[300,560,85],[290,565,80],[284.99,560,79]]


NUM_PRODUCTOS=3
NUM_PROVEEDORES=4

for precio in range(NUM_PRODUCTOS):
        
        promedio=float(0)
        
        for precio in range(NUM_PROVEEDORES):

            promedio =+ (precios[0][1]+precios[0][2]+precios[0][3]+precios[0][4])/NUM_PRODUCTOS
        print (promedio)
```

Comment: No veo pregunta, sólo veo código. ¿Qué le ocurre a tu código? ¿No funciona? ¿Por qué?

Comment: Dos `for` anidados compartiendo la misma variable `precio`. Malo. El operador `=+` no existe; ¿será `+=`?. La expresión para calcular `promedio` no tiene nada variable; siempre da el mismo resultado. `NUM_PROVEEDORES` es 4, pero en el código sólo se ven tres.

Comment: ¿Promedio de qué? ¿De cada proveedor? ¿De cada producto? ¿De la matriz entera? Explica lo que deseas obtener y el error que te está dando.